# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I tried  to access my website it shows an error lke

```html
This Page Isn't Working

www.abcdef.com didn't send any data

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

and showing this error for a few seconds it will redirect to original page.

In Google chrome console it showing following error

```html
POST https://www.abcde.com/Is_here/1542792525 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
send @ jquery.js:9566
ajax @ jquery.js:9173
jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:9322
(anonymous) @ place:2255
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ place:2253
```

and the code in which error occurs is

```html
setInterval(function(){ 
var c = "<?= TIME() ?>";
  $.post("<?= base_url() ?>Is_here/"+c,{a:"<?= $this->uri->segment(4) ?>",b:c,e:"<?= $this->uri->segment(5) ?>"},function(l_i){
     
    });
   },10000);
```

Comment: Hi there, have you tried another browser on the same site? Are we talking about an online website or are you still developing it on your local machine? In case is online is protected by SSL?

Comment: Edited the question with more details please have a look@Andrea

Comment: I see your site use SSL, have you tried it in another browser? Still the same errors?

Comment: No errors in Mozilla firefox, the error occurs  in google chrome.@ Andrea

Comment: Ok, so we can assume that it's not a problem with the website but with Chrome itself. Once I had the same error and following this discussion we resolved it. Have a look and let me know if it helps: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_7ncSGqOz8E

Answer (score 1):

`err_empty_response` was not the error from framework or website script.

Clear the cache from your browser or reset your browser then restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome do not allows cross domain AJAX, that's why i think your request is not classed as a simple request under the cross-origin request specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-cross-origin-request-0.

You can control this via HTTP header by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Setting it to `*` will accept cross-domain AJAX requests from any domain.

Using PHP, just add the following line into the script that you want to have access outside from your domain:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

and enable `mod_headers` module in `httpd.conf`.